# Hover on Div and change another, won't work?

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions

I have a Div and what I want to happen, is when you hover on div 1 it changes div 2.

So I can do this is CSS with `.div1:hover .div2`so this means that when I hover on 1, 2 will change.

I have used this before and even on the same style sheet, but for some reason it does not work .

This is the CSS.

```
#slide {
width:220%;
height:300px;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:0px;
-webkit-transition: left 2s linear;
-moz-transition: left 2s linear;
-ms-transition: left 2s linear;
-o-transition: left 2s linear;
transition: left 2s linear;
}
.six {
position:relative;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background-color:#F00;
}
.six:hover #slide {
left:-100%;
}
```

So this looks good to me and it works on the same style sheet, but something is stopping it?

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Is your `div2` contained within your `div1`? `.div1:hover .div2` translates to "Affects elements with class div2 that are children of an element with class div1 when that element is hovered over." (As an aside, `.div1:hover > .div2` would restrict the affected elements to those that are immediate children of the `div1` element.)

Comment: You really should include the HTML for this, so we can see how the elements are related, if at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.div1:hover .div2` selector refers to "an element with class `div2` that is a child of an element with class `div1` that is hovered over", so it will only work if `div2` is a child of `div1`.

If you need `div2` to be unrelated to `div1`, then you can only do this with JavaScript. Something like this (using the jQuery library):

```
$('.div1').hover(function() {
    $('.div2').addClass('div1-hovered-on');
}, function() {
    $('.div2').removeClass('div1-hovered-on');
});
```

Comment: Thanks that what I needed I did realise about the child element. Thanks.